# What MySql server configuration settings should I choose?

Tags: mysql

I'm a student and I'm taking a database class. We are installing MySQL on our computers to gain familiarity with the product. As I'm installing this on my personal computer, I remember the professor saying something about disabling the TCP/IP connectivity for security purposes, but I can't remember the specifics and when I setup my first local instance I chose to disable this option and selected the shared memory option (Windows installation). However, I was not able to connect to the server from my host.

Can anyone make some recommendations as to the appropriate connection options for me to choose when starting a server?

Thank you very much.

Comment: In what environment should the TCP/IP connectivity be disabled? Should installing MySQL on a personal computer for testing purposes apply this as well? Most of the times, what you've been taught in school are widely available online. Maybe a simple _"when do I need to disable TCP/IP connectivity option in MySQL"_ search can give you an answer.

Comment: If you use the shared memory option you can only connect from the PC running MySQL, which sounded like what you were doing. But when you say "not able to connect to the server from my host." It sounds like you are trying to connect to another PC where the MySQL server is runing. In that case you have to use the TCP/IP connectivity